# what's the matter with this grammar

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc, lr1

```
s   : cmd
    | cmd SOMETHING 

cmd :WORD
```

WORD and SOMETHING are non null terminals

it's an LR1 grammar so bison should parse it without problems.

however i faced an unexpected problem in runtime:
the program prompts for input twice, so for example when i enter "qwerty" it prompt for a second input,when  i try to debug it i get this:

```
Starting parse

Entering state 0

Reading a token: qwerty

Next token is token WORD

Shifting token WORD

Entering state 1

Reducing stack by rule 3 (line 20):

   $1 = token WORD ()

-> $$ = nterm cmd ()

Stack now 0

Entering state 3

Reading a token: 

(asks for input a second time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How will it know which rule for s to employ until it tries to read SOMETHING and either succeeds (second rule) or fails (first rule)?  Which means it HAS to ask for the second input.

Comment: it's based on the lookahead symbol which is $ here that mark the end of input

Comment: But it still needs to check that symbol, which involves asking for input.